# MySQL Multi Union Shortcut

Tags: mysql, loops, shortcut

I want to have a mysql table that will list data vertically without using table values.

Just like this.

`SELECT 0 AS vertical UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3;`

this will output

| vertical |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

now, is there a way to do this in much lesser code? if i want to list a total of up to 50?

Comment: which version of mysql you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use recursive CTE for generating range of numbers with or without gap of any range.

**Without GAP:**

```
-- MySQL (v8.0)
-- range between 0 to 50 with no gap
WITH RECURSIVE num_range (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0 -- starting the range
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 -- increment by 1
  FROM num_range 
  WHERE n < 50 -- last number
)
SELECT n
FROM num_range;
```

**With GAP:**

```
-- range between 0 to 50 with gap
WITH RECURSIVE num_range (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0 -- starting the range
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 2  -- increment by 2
  FROM num_range 
  WHERE n < 50 -- last number
)
SELECT n
FROM num_range;
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30e714fbb43b0d2bf55974bea50410f9